# Removing a noise pulse from a signal

Tags: audio-processing, noise-cancellation

I have a sampled audio signal that is corrupted with a noise pulse that occurs at regular intervals. The pulse is in the form of several periods of a sine wave, and I believe the frequency of that sine wave increases and decreases very slightly in a (seemingly) cyclic pattern.

Very roughly, I would say the pulses occur every 15 ms, and pulses are perhaps 1 ms in duration. Each pulse contains on the order of 10 periods of the sine wave.

I want to try to remove this pulse from the signal. My thought is to have a model of the pulse, and then estimate the pulse parameters such that I can precisely subtract it from the signal. There might be both coarse long-term estimates and fine per-pulse estimates.  Before I jump into this, do you any specific techniques that might apply here? I'm looking for something surprisingly easy to do (lol).

BTW, this is a hobby project (not homework, not commercial).

Comment: If you know, or can estimate the parameters of the noise (like frequency of the sinewave signal, duration, etc.) you could possibly use a matched-filter approach (I believe this is the right term) to perform detection and when the noise is detected subtract it from the signal. I haven’t tested that, but it’s an idea that comes to mind

Comment: I concur with @ZaellixA: start by trying to localize the noise pulses using something like a matched filter approach.  Then do duration / phase / frequency / amplitude estimation on each pulse (especially if those parameters vary) and then subtract that from the original signal over the duration of the pulse.

Comment: @ZaellixA Thanks for the feedback. It was along the lines of what I was thinking with a matched filter. My guess is I am in store for some real world (aka cruel world) experience lol.

Comment: @gschro, believe me, if there’s no deadline the world is wonderful ;D…!!! So, if this is a hobby project as you say then it’s nice to work on it on your own time and convenience.

Answer (score 4):

Since you know both impulses' carrier frequency and cyclic frequency, you might want to take advantage of both of them. The method used to take advantage of both of them is called the FRESH filtering.

This filtering optimal by the means of least squares and is given by
$$\hat{x}(t)=\int g(t,u)y(u)du$$
where $g(t,u)$ is the periodic optimal filter.
For each value of the age variable, $\tau=t-u$, the optimal filter is given by
$$g(t,u)=\sum_{\eta} g_{\eta}(t-u)e^{2\pi j\eta u}$$
where $g(t-u)$ are the Fourier coefficients and $\eta$ is the modulation frequency (or its harmonic).

For the discretely sampled signal, the filtering takes the following form
$$\hat{x}(n)=\sum_{\eta, \tau}g_{\eta}(\tau)y(n-\tau)$$

In vector notation you can define
$$\vec{g}=\left[g_{\eta_0}(0),...g_{\eta_0}(\tau_{max}),..g_{\eta_{max}}(0),...g_{\eta_{max}}(\tau_{max})\right]$$
and estimate the filter coefficients by
$$\hat{\vec{g}}=\left[[y]^H[y]\right]^{-1}\left[[y]^H\vec{y}\right]$$
where
$$[y]=[\vec{y}_{\eta_0}^{0},\vec{y}_{\eta_0}^{1},...,\vec{y}_{\eta_0}^{\tau_{max}},...\vec{y}_{\eta_{max}}^{\tau_{max}}]$$
where $\vec{y}_{\eta_k}^{q}$ is the input signal delayed by $q$ samples and shifted by $\eta_k$ frequency (the shifting is done by multiplication with a complex exponent in the time domain).

Attaching the [original parer link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/212375/) but there are other sources I might add in case that anyone will take an interest in this answer and ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the paper. Before going too much further I need to characterize the signal better, to understand how much jitter there is the various parameters.

Comment: @gschro, great have . Let me know what is missing to be accepted...